# CSS - Hide every element of the same kind except the first - not child

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

I've been trying to figure out the way to hide every 'label' element in the html below except the first one. I've got a repeater field that adds a row with a dropdown select field and a label.

Each new row adds the select field and the label. The label id starts with 'label-repeat- ' and the suffix is dynamically generated based on the number of repeater rows, so it goes: 'label-repeat-1', 'label-repeat-2', 'label-repeat-3' etc.

The issue is that each repeater row is separately wrapped into its own div, so I'm guessing I cannot use `:not(:first-child)` in the case.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywn2krmx/) and below is my html:

```
<div class="fieldset">
  <div class="status">
   <label id="label-repeat-1" class="label-repeater">Status</label>
   <select id="field-repeat-1" class="field-repeater">
     <option value="Open">Open</option>
     <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fieldset">
  <div class="status">
   <label id="label-repeat-2" class="label-repeater">Status</label>
   <select id="field-repeat-2" class="field-repeater">
     <option value="Open">Open</option>
     <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fieldset">
  <div class="status">
   <label id="label-repeat-3" class="label-repeater">Status</label>
   <select id="field-repeat-3" class="field-repeater">
     <option value="Open">Open</option>
     <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been trying to use the wildcard selector to select the label with `label[id^='label-repeat-'], label[id*=' label-repeat-']` which works fine, but then I'm trying to add the `:nth-of-type(n+2)` pseudo class to select every label except the first one and hide it, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
label[id^='label-repeat-']:nth-of-type(n+2),
label[id*=' label-repeat-']:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Is there any other way to do this with CSS? Or even jQuery?

Comment: yes... what do u want?

Comment: I though the title sums it all, but I've been trying to figure out how to hide every 'label' element except the first one.

Comment: You use `.fieldset:nth-of-type(n+2) label{...}` or something like it, depending on what you actually want.  Also: Your labels are missing the `for` attribute, THE reason why you should use labels.

Comment: Ah - no, "*except the first - not child*" made no sense (to me) and it's not "following".  But thanks for clarifying.  You want to hide the `label` - but *not* the corresponding `select`?

Comment: To add to @cloned 's comment: if you target the fieldset, you could use your not first-child attempt:  `.fieldset:not(:first-child) label {...`

Comment: I only need to hide the label - not the entire fieldset nor the status.

Comment: Yes, that's what our CSS is doing. It target's the non first labels.

Comment: @freedomn-m @cloned Ah yes, that works `.fieldset:not(:first-child) label {}` sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: @cloned if you want to type it as an answer I'm happy to accept. Thanks again.

Comment: You originally had this tagged as [tag:jquery] but seems you're after [tag:css] - in jquery you could also do this `$("label.label-repeater:gt(0)").hide();` as it works on the collection of labels, not their sibling-position - I would use css if you can as jquery solution will give FOUC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want to hide all except for the first label.  So, you would end up with a label and 3 select boxes under it?  Using the "plus" combinator in CSS is the easiest way of saying "all but the first one"...

```
.fieldset + .fieldset label {
  display:none;
}
```

This rule is saying any fieldset that is followed by another fieldset (all but the first one), then the nested label under those.